# Why do I get an undocumented value for MSBTS_HostInstance ClusterInstanceType?

Tags: wmi, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Why do I get an undocumented value for MSBTS_HostInstance  ClusterInstanceType?

I'm getting values of "3" for the ClusterInstanceType when I do a query of the BizTalk cluster ...

```
Get-CIMInstance -ClassName MSBTS_HostInstance -NameSpace root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer
```

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578062.aspx) documentation, the expected values are ...

- 0 - UnClusteredInstance
- 1 - ClusteredInstance
- 2 - ClusteredVirtualInstance

So what is the "3", and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this script here [Error Attempting to Bounce Clustered Host](http://biztalkdeployment5.rssing.com/chan-9501834/all_p23.html), 3 is HostIsClusteredManager (cluster manager node)